# Visual Studio - Mark file as optional

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio we have a custom user.config file that the developer can use to set custom app settings. I do not want to check this file into source control since the build server will use the default settings if user.config is not found.

If visual studio is missing the file, it throws a "cannot find file" compile time exception.

In the csproj build file, is there a way I can mark the file to be ignored when compiling if not found?

Comment: Visual Studio automatically re-creates the file if it's missing. I've never seen a compile-time error thrown when the `user.config` file was missing. I also do not check it into my source control system. Are you *sure* that's the file that's causing the compiler error? What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: its not app.config, its a custom config file I added myself. app.config points to it.